# Prevenir arquivo js de executar

Tags: javascript, jquery, navegador-de-internet

Gostaria de saber como faço para prevenir ou modificar um arquivo .js de um site ao ser executado no meu browser. O site possui o seguinte código

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/play.html.js?_v=1.1.1">
```

Esse script play.html.js, faz com o que quando um video na pagina perca o foco, ele pause. Toda vez que desfoco a janela ele muda o atributo da body de `<body class="visible">` para `<body class="hidden">`, eu utilizo dois monitores em meu pc, e gostaria de dexar o video tocando em um monitor enquanto mexo no outro.

Como posso fazer para mudar essa função do site ?

Comment: Já tentou manipular o elemento da tag `<video>`?

Comment: @downvoters: por que o downvote? a pergunta parece legítima.

Comment: Sim, o código da pagina nao contem a tag <video> tudo é feito via jquery. E o video é colocado dentro da div video-container. Unica coisa que realmente muda no codigo da pagina são as mudanças de atributos da body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer um user script para alterar o funcionamento do site, usando a extensão [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (caso use Firefox) ou [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) (caso use Chrome), que reverta o que o `play.html.js` faz, com algo tipo:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var classes = body.className.split(' ');
if (classes.indexOf('hidden') >= 0){
    classes.pop('hidden');
    classes.push('visible');
    body.className = classes.join(' ');
}
```

Você provavelmente precisará fazer alguma modificação nesse script, limitar para executar apenas no domínio e na página correta, mas o caminho é esse.

Comment: Foi uma das primeiras coisas que tentei, ate olhei alguns codigos de gringo pra tentar resolver mas nao deu certo. Tentei fazer o script como ta o seu e a classe body continua mudando.

O script: http://pastebin.com/w64qpaWR

Comment: Hmm, é provável que o script no `play.html.js` esteja executando depois do user script. Experimente fazer com um: `setInterval(function(){ /* codigo aqui dentro */ }, 3000);` -- que vai ficar verificando a cada 3s. É meio gambi, mas já deve quebrar o galho.

Comment: @user3017878 conseguiu testar? deu certo?

Comment: Testei. Era exatamente isso, fiquei a tarde inteira ontem quebrando a cabeça pra descobrir isso e nao ia nem fudeno. Muito Obrigado mesmo. Unico problema é que fica parando de 3 em 3 segundos, nao teria como executar o meu script antes do play.html.js?

Comment: @user3017878 De nada! =) Então, vc quer na verdade executar o seu script _depois_ do `play.html.js` (se executar antes ele vai sobrescrever, que é o que tá acontecendo). Você pode tentar só trocar o `setInterval` pra `setTimeout` e ir aumentando o delay (talvez 5000) pra fazer ele executar depois do `play.html.js`. Não sei se tem como garantir isso.

Comment: Tava pensando em outra solução, tipo trocar o .pause() por .play(). Ou então sempre que for executado um .pause(), executar um .play(). O problema é em fazer o script, não sei como pegar o evento .pause e não sei a id do elemento video.

Comment: Vc testou com o `setTimeout()` e não funcionou?

Comment: Funcionou sim, mas queria ver se era possivel modificar a função do pause, tava querendo aprender um pouco mais sore o GM e funções do javascript. Tem como fazer um script pra trocar um .pause() por .play() ou executar um .play() depois de um .pause() ?

Comment: @user3017878 Olha, aí vai depender de como isso está implementado, vc terá que ler e entender o código do `play.html.js` pra saber. Se estiver muito encapsulado, pode ser difícil. Bem, se a minha resposta ajudou, vc pode marcá-la como aceita (no V embaixo da opção pra votar). =)